# Exact same dataframe shows different rows in python on different laptops

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, slice

I am having a strange problem today.
We have a python code used by different users, which is basically reading a xls file. The strange thing is, it's reading the exact same file differently on different laptops.

Both laptops have the latest python version.

On my laptop I am getting 7 rows, and on a different laptop I am getting 8 - on the exact same xls we read with the exact same code.

The xls actually looks like the example below for laptop 2 - so it starts with three empty rows, however, laptop 1 only returns two.

my code is super basic:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

os.chdir(r'C:\Python_test')

xls= pd.ExcelFile('dataframe.xlsx')
di = pd.read_excel(xls,'tab2')
di
```

result for di on laptop 1:

```
      Unnamed:0   Unnamed:1   Unnamed:2   Unnamed:3
0           NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
1           NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2           NaN         NaN     column1      value1
3           NaN         NaN     column2      value2
4           NaN         NaN     column3      value3
5           NaN         NaN     column4      value4
6           NaN         NaN     column5      value5
7           NaN         NaN     column6      value6
```

result for di on laptop 2:

```
      Unnamed:0   Unnamed:1   Unnamed:2   Unnamed:3
0           NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
1           NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2           NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
3           NaN         NaN     column1      value1
4           NaN         NaN     column2      value2
5           NaN         NaN     column3      value3
6           NaN         NaN     column4      value4
7           NaN         NaN     column5      value5
8           NaN         NaN     column6      value6
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is the case?
I first of all thought it might be the python version - but after upgrading all to the same version, it was still the same.

Thank you!

Comment: is it the exact same version of pandas?

Comment: check pandas version print(pd.__version__)

Comment: excellent hint, let me check that!

Comment: So, we have 0.23.4 (laptop 1) vs 0.24.2 (laptop 2) - will update the .23 to .24 and recheck

Comment: thank you so much! this was the reason for the difference :-)